# Javascript - Issue with playing video on hover

Tags: javascript, video

```
    var figure = jQuery(".nb-client-video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

    function hoverVideo(e) {  
        jQuery('video', this).get(0).play(); 
    }

    function hideVideo(e) {
        jQuery('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
    }

<div class="nb-client-video">
<video muted loop playsinline>
<source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/videos/emaar-new.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>                                    
</div>
```

Hey guys I want to play this video only on hover. I tried using the above code but not working. Can you guys help me to find out what causing issue please. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

remove the dot from jQuery(".video")

```
jQuery("video")
```

Comment: That is a outer div of video bro.

Comment: I meant when we hover on that div the video should play.

Comment: there is no .video class in your code just .nb-client-video. What do you want to match with .video?

Comment: I'm sorry that was my mistake and I have updated the code. Can you please check now?

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
$(".nb-client-video").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('video').play();
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).find('video').pause();
    }
);
```